# Micromax 353G Modem in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: internet, usb-modem

I am using MMX 353g modem in windows and its working well but no matter what i do i cannot make it work in Ubuntu 12.04. I have made a connection but it doesnt show up in connection list. I tried lot of things from different forums nothing seems to work for me, please help.

Comment: Just now i did the following reducing my problem a bit,      sudo gedit /etc/modules
At the bottom of the file, make two new lines, like this:
usbserial
option                                                            Since I was running from usb stick I used the following commands to load these modules:
sudo modprobe usbserial 
sudo modprobe option                                                         Now connection is detected when i try to connect it gets connected as well but surprisingly i cannot access the net no webpage can be browsed ??? please solve this for me

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these lines to `/etc/modules` file:

```
lp
usbserial
option
```